# Unrecognized font-family 'open-sans-bold '

Tags: ios, react-native, font-family, custom-font

I am trying to add custom fonts to my bare react native project and I keep getting `Unrecognized font-family 'open-sans-bold '` on the ios similator. I added the fonts fold in my assets folder with files `open-sans.ttf and open-sans-bold.ttf` I also have `react-native.config.js` with the content below

```js
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
};
```

I run npx react-native link and I checked the info.plist file and I have the fonts in `<key>UIAppFonts</key>` I tried different solutions but none of them worked for me.